# Is it possible to disable hover event in CSS if element have class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to disable **hover event** in CSS if element **have class**?

Comment: Hover *event* (javascript), or hover *style* (css) ? Care to share some code?

Comment: By default element has *nothing* assigned to hover event.

Comment: Maybe just give it a different rule. `elem:hover { the rules } elem.class:hover { some other rules }`

Answer (score 11):

You could use the `:not()` selector:

```css
.myElement {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #CADE75;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #6D6D6D;
}

/* important bit */
.myElement:not(.dontHover):hover {
    background: #b5d335;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="myElement">An element that hovers</a>
<a href="#" class="myElement dontHover">An element that doesn't</a>
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pointer-events: none`, but this will disable all pointer related events, including click.

```
a.class {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Does not work: `#DialogsUsers .active:hover {
    pointer-events: none;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the best way to do this is to use 2 classes.

With something like this for html:

```
<div class="foo"> bar </div>
<div class="foo hoverClass"> foobar </div>
```

And then you could have CSS that looks something like this:

```
.foo {/* CSS here */}
.hoverClass:hover{/* CSS here */}
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/d5gkjmf2/) a fiddle of the example

Comment: This does the opposite of what's requested